# what is the right way to clear QlistWidgetItem using clicked event in python

Tags: python, list, append, qlistwidgetitem

Python function that on click **search button** it should do:

1. Read files and check if there is a matching it will append the
   file to a list.
2. Clear the existing list
3. Display the new list

The problem is that if the user **try to search again**  the function do **not clear the content of the list** yet append the file name to the list.

First time search

[image]

Second time search

[image]

## code:

```
def displayFileTerList(self):

        searchedSTR = self.lineEditSearch.text()

        for file in self.fileList:
            try:

                with open(file) as ctf:
                    ctfRead = ctf.read()
                matches = re.findall(searchedSTR, ctfRead, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

                if matches:
                    self.listWidgetPDFlist.clear()
                    self.filteredList.append(file)


            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


        self.listWidgetPDFlist.addItems(self.filteredList)
```

Comment: `self.filteredList` still contains the previous items. Clear this list, too.

Comment: @RomhaKorev this was the issue thank you add your comment as question to vote it up